# Postges call procedure for each row of a returning delete statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a delete statement and I want to call a procedure for each of the rows affected by it.  Currently I only seem to be able to access a single row of the set that was deleted.

That is if the delete statement below affects multiple rows then I only see a single passed to my `analytics` procedure

```
create or replace function platform.update_foo() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
  declare
    result record;
  begin
      with affected_rows as (
        delete from private.foo
        where environment_id=new.environment_id
          and name=new.name
        returning *
      )
      select private.analytics(affected_rows, 'cancelled')
      from affected_rows into result;
    return new;
  end;
$$;
```

My analytics function has a signature like so

```
analytics(f private.foo, t varchar default null)
returns void as $$
begin
  -- ...
```

Comment: BEFORE DELETE triggers should return OLD, not NEW.

Comment: Please show the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Comment: How do you know that there are multiple `affected_rows` but `analytics` is called only once? Btw, `result` will only hold at most one record, so that might be an issue.